# Problemas con el login en php y sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, php7, login, alert

Vean estoy haciendo un login con php 7.2 y sql server 2018, estoy usando variables de sesión para poder realizar el cambio de menú dependiendo del rol(perfil) del usuario y un procedimiento almacenado que se encarga de validar si los datos que fueron ingresados en el formulario coinciden con los que se encuentran en la base de datos.

El problema es el siguiente,resulta que cuando se ingresan los datos y se envía al archivo en donde se valida el formulario de login, se ejecuta la variable que tiene el procedimiento almacenado y se valida con un if para saber si devolvió datos, resulta que cuando se comprueba que los datos ingresados en el formulario del login hacen que el procedimiento almacenado devuelva al menos 1 dato, se envia a la pagina principal con el memú correspondiente pero no se ejecuta el alert que le da la bienvenida al usuario, y cuando se ingresan mal los datos, por ejemplo la contraseña, no me dice que los datos ingresados fueron incorrectos sino que me muestra varios errores con las variables de sesión y ahí si ejecuta el alert con el mensaje de bienvenida. Aquí las imágenes...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que debería de salir el alert con el mensaje de datos incorrectos pero da el mensaje de bienvenida... Como puedo hacer para que el formulario sea validado de manera correcta.... Muchas gracias de antemano!!!

Este es el código de PHP:

```
 <?php
//// Se agrega la conexion a la base de datos
include ('ConexionBD.php');
//Declaración de la variables que van a recibir los datos del formlario Login
$Correo_Electronico = $_POST["CorreoElectronico"];
$Contraseña = $_POST["Contraseña"];
//Varible contadora que va a evitar que el ciclo sea infinito
$i = 0;
//Variable que trae el procedimineto almacenado de la base de datos
$sql = "EXEC PA_Usuario_Login '$Correo_Electronico','$Contraseña'";
//Ejecuta la consulta
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($Conn,$sql);
//Condicional que valida si la consulta trajo datos
if ($stmt > 0){
   // //Ciclo que obtiene los datos devueltos por el procedimiento almacenado
    while($Fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
       $Nombre = $Fila["Nombre"];
       $Apellido_1 = $Fila["Apellido_1"];
       $Apellido_2 = $Fila["Apellido_2"];
       $E_mail = $Fila["E_mail"];
       $Telefono = $Fila["Telefono"];
       $Rol = $Fila["Rol"];
       $i++;
    }
    //Si los datos coinciden, se crea una sesión para el usuario
    //Comienza la sesión
    session_start();
   //Se crean las variables de la sesión
    $_SESSION['NombreUs'] = $Nombre;
    $_SESSION['ApellidoUs_1']= $Apellido_1;
    $_SESSION['ApellidoUs_2']= $Apellido_2;
    $_SESSION['E_mail'] = $E_mail;
    $_SESSION['Telefono'] = $Telefono;
    $_SESSION['Rol'] = $Rol;
    //Redirecciona a la página principal
    header("Location:../Vistas/Principal.php");
   //Mensaje de bienvenida
    echo'
     <script>
            alert("Bienvenido");
      </script>
    ';

}else{
   echo'
   <script>
   alert("Correo electrónico o contraseña incorrectos");
   window.history.go(-1)
   </script>
   ';
}
```

Este es código del procedimiento almacenado en SQL Server:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PA_Usuario_Login]
    @E_mail varchar(50),
    @Contraseña varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    select Nombre,Apellido_1,Apellido_2,E_mail,Telefono,Rol from Usuario
    where E_mail=@E_mail and Contraseña=@Contraseña;
END
```

Este el código de HTML de la página a la cual redirecciona el login cuando los datos son correctos:

```
    <?php
//Se abre el código php para lo que es el inicio de la sesión
//Se reanuda la sesion que se abrió en ValidaLogin.php
session_start();
//Se crea una variable que tenga la varible de sesión que trae el rol del usuario
$Rol = $_SESSION['Rol'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../CSS/Bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../CSS/Principal.css">
    <title>Pagina Principal</title>
</head>
<body>
       <!-- Barra del menú -->
 <header>
    <?php
    //Se abre el código php 
        //Condicional que valida que tipo de usuario fue el que ingresó
        //A = Administrador
        //E = Empleado
        //U = Usuario
        if($Rol == 'A'){
            //Incluye el menu con respecto al rol de usuario que ingresó
            include("../Vistas/MenuAdministrador.php");
        }
        else if($Rol == 'E'){
            //Incluye el menu con respecto al rol de usuario que ingresó
            include("../Vistas/MenuVisitante.php");
            }else if($Rol == 'U'){
                //Incluye el menu con respecto al rol de usuario que ingresó
                include("../Vistas/MenuVisitante.php");
            }
    ?>
</header>
<!-- Termina la barra del menú -->
<!-- Descripción de la historia de la ferretería -->
 <div id="contenedor"> 
    <div class="container">
        <section class="row-fluid Principal container"> 
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 Caja1">
            <h1>¿Quiénes somos?</h1> 
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Ducimus illum nam impedit aliquid minus necessitatibus 
                        voluptatum facilis eveniet dicta libero aperiam error 
                        illo voluptate aspernatur, earum accusantium soluta, 
                        magnam officiis.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 Caja2">
                    <h1>Visión</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Ducimus illum nam impedit aliquid minus necessitatibus 
                        voluptatum facilis eveniet dicta libero aperiam error 
                        illo voluptate aspernatur, earum accusantium soluta, 
                        magnam officiis.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 Caja3">
                    <h1>Misión</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Ducimus illum nam impedit aliquid minus necessitatibus 
                        voluptatum facilis eveniet dicta libero aperiam error 
                        illo voluptate aspernatur, earum accusantium soluta, 
                        magnam officiis.</p>
                </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Pie de página -->
<footer>
    <?php
        include("Footer.php");
    ?>
</footer>
</body>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Este es el código HTML del formulario de login:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- LLamada de la hoja de estilos -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../CSS/Bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/Login.css">
    <title>Inicio de sesión</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class=" navbar navbar-default nav navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-1">
                            <span class="sr-only"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <img class="Imagen"src="../Imagenes/LOGO.png" alt="FYDBB">
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="Principal.php">Empresa</a></li>
                            <li class="active"><a href="Ofertas.php">Ofertas</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cotizar</a></li>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                    Productos
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                                <li><a href="#">Familia#1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Familia#2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Familia#3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Familia#4</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="">Ver Productos</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar artículo">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                        </form>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                Ayuda
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                    Iniciar sesión
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                                <li><a href="Login.php">Ingresar</a></li>
                                <li><a href="CrearCuenta.php">Crear cuenta</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header> 
        <div id="contenedor">
          <form action="../scripts/ValidaLogin.php" id="Formulario" method="POST">
                <h1>Iniciar sesión</h1>
                <br>
                <label>Correo electrónico</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="CorreoElectronico" id="Email" placeholder="&#128272; Correo electrónico">
                <label>Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Contraseña" id="Contraseña" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Iniciar sesión">
                <input type="buttom" class= "btn btn-danger" value="Crear cuenta">
                <a href="">Olvidé mi contraseña</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    <footer>
        <?php
            include("Footer.php");
        ?>
    </footer>
</body>
<!-- Sciripts para el uso de JQuery y Bootstrap -->
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu condicional

```
if ($stmt > 0){
```

Por esto para que te devuelva el numero de columnas

```
if(sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt) > 0){
```

Comment: Lo cambie pero me lanza el alert de que los datos estan incorrectos cuando ingreso los mismos datos que tengo en la base de datos....Todavia no me funciona...

Comment: Intenta cambiar en sql server las ñ por n y si no funciona cámbialas en todos los lugares que la utilices.

Comment: Pero eso lo cambio en el código de php y sql por que en sql la consulta funciona bien....